# How to replace compound words in a string using a dictionary?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, nlp, normalization

I have a dictionary whose key:value pairs correspond to compound words and the expression i want to replace them for in a text. For example let's say:

```
terms_dict = {'digi conso': 'digi conso', 'digi': 'digi conso', 'digiconso': 'digi conso', '3xcb': '3xcb', '3x cb': '3xcb', 'legal entity identifier': 'legal entity identifier'}
```

**My goal is to create a function replace_terms(text, dict) that takes a text and a dictionary like this one as parameters, and returns the text after replacing the compound words.**

For instance, this script:

```
test_text = "i want a digi conso loan for digiconso" 

print(replace_terms(test_text, terms_dict))
```

Should return:

```
"i want a digi conso loan for digi conso"
```

---

I have tried using .replace() but for some reasons it doesn't work properly, probably because the terms to replace are composed of multiple words.

I also tried this:

```
def replace_terms(text, terms_dict):
    if len(terms_dict) > 0:
        words_in = [k for k in terms_dict.keys() if k in text]  # ex: words_in = [digi conso, digi, digiconso]
        if len(words_in) > 0:
            for w in words_in:
                pattern = r"\b" + w + r"\b"
                text = re.sub(pattern, terms_dict[w], text)

    return text
```

But when applied to my text, this function returns: *"i want a digi conso conso loan for digi conso"*, the word *conso* get's doubled and I can see why (because the words_in list is created by going through the dictionary keys, and the text is not altered when one key is appended to the list).

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather quick and wonky way of doing this:

```py
from typing import Dict, List, Tuple


def replace_terms(text: str, terms: Dict[str, str]) -> str:
    replacement_list: List[Tuple[int, str]] = []
    check = True
    for term in terms:
        if term in text:
            for replacement in replacement_list:
                if replacement[0] == text.index(term):
                    if len(term) > len(replacement[1]):
                        replacement_list.remove(replacement)
                    else:
                        check = False
            if check:
                replacement_list.append((text.index(term), term))
            else:
                check = True
    for replacement in replacement_list:
        text = text.replace(replacement[1], terms[replacement[1]], 1)
    return text
```

Usage:

```py
terms_dict = {
    "digi conso": "digi conso",
    "digi": "digi conso",
    "digiconso": "digi conso",
    "3xcb": "3xcb",
    "3x cb": "3xcb",
    "legal entity identifier": "legal entity identifier"
}

test_text = "i want a digi conso loan for digiconso"

print(replace_terms(test_text, terms_dict))
```

Result:

```
i want a digi conso loan for digi conso
```

Comment: Nice one, it's not bulletproof but it's perfectly fine for what i'm trying to do. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```py
terms_dict = { 'digiconso': 'digi conso', '3xcb': '3xcb', '3x cb': '3xcb', 'legal entity identifier': 'legal entity identifier'}
test_text = "i want a digi conso loan for digiconso" 
def replace_terms(txt, dct):
    dct = tuple(dct.items())
    for x, y in dct:
        txt = txt.replace(x, y, 1)
    return txt
print(replace_terms(test_text, terms_dict))
```

First I get the dict pairs and get them in a easier form(tuple). Then I iter and replace!

Output:

`i want a digi conso loan for digi conso`

You had to many extra replace identifiers which you did not need. I also made it only replace 1 but you can change that.

Comment: Hi @thatrandomperson and thank you for your help. The thing is that I also need those other identifiers because I won't only be using that function over the test_text i wrote, but I will use it to normalize a text with thousands of lines. The terms_dict i posted is only a part of the whole dictionnary, which is longer (about 500 terms).

Comment: @Perrupi there is no basic way to regulate interference. you'll have to spilt your dict into different parts depending on which line or something.

Comment: yes probably the best thing to do would be to format my dictionary, i'll look into that.